# Dart future with non async function

Tags: dart, async-await

I am creating a function for firebase phone auth using Dart. There are two functions getCredential and then signIn. When using a try/catch block I am unsure of how this should be coded. Should the non-async function `getCredential` be outside of the try/catch block or inside?

Should it be coded as:

```
  // Sign in with phone
  Future signInWithPhoneNumber(String verificationId, String smsCode) async {
    AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Or should it be coded like this?

```
  // Sign in with phone
  Future signInWithPhoneNumber(String verificationId, String smsCode) async {
    try {
      AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: smsCode,
      );
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

If coded as the second option does the try/catch only work with the async function or both. For example, if the `getCredential` function generated an error would it be caught in the catch block?

Comment: generally if you don't await the future and you don't catch the error with `catchError` the exception won't be handled

Answer (score 0):

Yes the catch will handle anything that throws in your try block, it's not async specific. To confirm this you could write a function that gets called at the beginning of the try for example:

```
// this is a function that throws
void doSomething(String param) {
   if (param == null) {
     throw FormatException('param can not be null'); 
   }
}


Future signInWithPhoneNumber(String verificationId, String smsCode) async {
  try {
    doSomething(null); // this will be caught
    AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    return user;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString()); // this prints 'FormatException: param can not be null'
    return null;
  }
}
```

So async is not related to whether your function will be caught or not so it's better to use the second option.